# Call a function before outputting headers in PHP?

Tags: php

Is there any way to have PHP automatically call a function, before a script outputs any HTTP headers?

I'm looking for something like [register-shutdown-function](http://us.php.net/register-shutdown-function), but to register a function that's called **before** the output is already sent, not after. I want my function to send a header, so I need something that's called earlier.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could also trap everything with `ob_start` and then register a callback function to be used when you send the page with `ob_end_flush`.  Check out the PHP manual for [OB_START](https://www.php.net/ob_start)

Comment: Looks like this is about as close as you can get.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it is what you are looking for but you might want to investigate using auto_prepend_file in your php.ini or setting it in an .htaccess file. If you set an auto_prepend_file it will automatically include that file before running each script.

[auto_prepend_file](http://www.askapache.com/php/use-phpini-to-add-http-headers-to-output.html)

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum88/1225.htm
You'd be using PHP's header() function to send a header (which must be called before any other output), but using your function before/during the call.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not quite what I'm looking for. I could always call header() manually, but I'm trying to avoid making a change to every place where I return output.

Comment: In other words, I want the function to be evaluated as late as possible, before the headers are sent. I don't want to start sending the headers earlier than I was before.