# Locating in Php with echoing Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

Why locating in `PHP` with echoing `Javascript` dangerous and not recommended?

Why I can't have `function header()` before any output?

And how can I do?

Example:

```
echo("<script>location.href = 'some-website.php';</script>");
```

Comment: What do you mean with `locating in Php with echoing Javascript`?  Include a minimal code example, to explain what you mean. Also the second part of your question is not clear.

Comment: @t.niese Done. Look up.

Comment: May be your second question's [answer is here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/392088/7678788)

Comment: `echo("<script>location.href = 'some-website.php';</script>");` is not recommended, because there is already standardized way to inform the client that a redirect has to be do using the response headers `header('Location: some-website.php')`.

Comment: OK, but with header() I have to carry about having header() before any output, with Javascript I don't. So?

Comment: This is explained in the question linked by ChiragJain